# Using stars and bars method.

Tags: combinatorics

There are 24 chairs in a row on which we place 5 final test, with at most 1 test per chair. In how many ways can this be done if no two adjacent chairs can have an test?

using the method I got that there would be 19 stars and 5 bars which are tests, but I'm confused on what to do with the no two adjacent chairs can have an test part next

Comment: There are other ways to solve this problem.  Do you have to use this method?

Comment: For this specific part I have to @N.F.Taussig

Comment: Are tests to be distinguished from each another?

Comment: test are the same @MathLover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As tests are same, it is still a problem that can be solved using Stars and Bars method (or call them Sticks and Stones). First, we have $5$ chairs with tests. Now we are left with $19$ chairs. We place $4$ of them between the chairs with tests so chairs with tests are no longer adjacent to each another. Now we need to decide how many of the remaining $15$ chairs go in each of the $6$ spaces (between chairs with tests or at two ends). So we are looking for number of solutions to,

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 15$, where $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5$ and $x_6$ are non-negative integers.

Applying sticks and stones, the answer would be $ \displaystyle {15 + 6 - 1 \choose 6 - 1}$

Comment: it's after long that someone said sticks and stones!